# How can I translate or add words that seems not to be part of core strings?

Tags: theming, 8, i18n-l10n

I currently use `formatPlural()` to translate *comment* (not *comments*) and return its value to the Twig template.

```
\Drupal::translation()->formatPlural('', '1 comment', '@count comments');
```

Is there any way to use code similar to the following one in a Twig template to translate this word?

```
{{ 'comment'|trans }}
{{ 'comment'|t }}
{% trans %}comment{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't? There is no reason why that wouldn't work. The only thing is that you have to actually visit that page in a language different from english so they are tracked and you can add translations.

Comment: Also, you cannot use `\Drupal::translation()->formatPlural('', '1 comment', '@count comments')` to translate _comment_ since, `formatPlural()` expects a number as first argument, and it would eventually translate _1 comment_, not _comment_.

Comment: @Berdir I search for "comment"  word in User interface translation section but seems does not exist any string on the filter result.